# How can I transfer information about HTTPS session from embedded browser to Web Service client?

Tags: .net, web-services, https, saml

I have a .NET/C# application which hosts an embedded browser and Web Service client. The embedded browser has HTTPS connection (SAML). How can I transfer this HTTPS connection to the Web Service WCF client?

UPDATE: Similar approach for mobile applications is described here:

https://github.com/okta/okta-mobile-connect

https://developer.pingidentity.com/en/resources/napps-native-app-sso.html

Comment: A connection cannot be "transfered" as such. Before being a programmer's question, it's an infrastructure/security question. It depends on your SAML implementation, and on your web service implementation. Check this out for example: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38802/how-is-saml-solving-the-cross-domain-single-sign-on-problem

Comment: SAML is implemented by embedded browser.

Comment: So is it correct to say what you're actually trying to do is transfer a SAML authentication token which has been downloaded in the embedded browser and access/use it in your web service client?

Comment: Correct. Not sure about HTTPS session.